# Javascript/jquery for multiple dropdown menus on one page

Tags: javascript, dropdown

How can I use the same javascript/jquery for multiple drop down on a single page? Would I select by ID or class?

These are one the same page:

```
<select id="drop1">
<option value="#">Option 1</option>
<option value="#">Option 2</option>
<option value="#">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2">
<option value="#">Option 1</option>
<option value="#">Option 2</option>
<option value="#">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

What javascript/jquery should I use to have the page redirect to the correct URL when an option is selected? Functionality should be the same for both dropdowns, but each have unique IDs. I'm not opposed to using the same class for both dropdown (instead of unique IDs) if that method would be easier.

Comment: Are you saying that the selection of an option should redirect the user to another page? For example, selecting Option 1 from drop1 will immediately take me to http://yourserver.com/option1.html.

Comment: Yes, selecting an option from the dropdown should redirect the user to the page url from the value. The same logic applies to both dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

If the behavior is both the same then you can either create listeners for the individual IDs, or use the same class and add the listener to that class.  To prevent duplicate code, I would suggest the class approach.

```
<select id="drop1" class="urlRedirect">
  <option selected disabled>--Select--</option>
  <option value="page1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="page2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="page3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2" class="urlRedirect">
  <option selected disabled>--Select--</option>
  <option value="page4">Option 1</option>
  <option value="page5">Option 2</option>
  <option value="page6">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And then the jquery:

```
 $('select.urlRedirect').change(function() {
  //alert($(this).val());
  //window.location.href=$(this).val(); to open in same page
  window.open(
    $(this).val(),
    '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
  );
});
```

Working jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/aarbor989/y0yjouo0/](https://jsfiddle.net/bnpeLo62/)

Comment: Thank you! But what would the actual code be? I am unsure of that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use the "onchange" event of the SELECT. You don't need to use jQuery or the "id" attribute.

```
<select id="drop1" onchange="launch(this)">
    <option value="/drop1opt1.html">Option 1</option>
    <option value="/drop1opt2.html">Option 2</option>
    <option value="/drop1opt3.html">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2" onchange="launch(this)">
    <option value="/drop2opt1.html">Option 1</option>
    <option value="/drop2opt2.html">Option 2</option>
    <option value="/drop2opt3.html">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Then create a simple javascript function to change the window's location property.

```
function launch(opt) {
    window.location = opt.value;
}
```

Hope that helps.